# Randoms failures on json.net deserialization through WebRequest

Tags: c#, ios, json.net

I'm using Json.NET for deserializing json files sent by the API server on an iOS client (with Monotouch). I have a really weird problem because sometimes the deserialization fails with randoms exceptions. I hadn't any problem before and I think it started since the json files went bigger. When it happens, I just ask the application to try again and after a random number of times (and randoms different exceptions) the deserialization finally works, for no reason.

Here are the different exceptions I got:

```
  2013-02-12 19:14:58.307 client_ios[2176:4303] Failed to deserialize: Unexpected end of content while loading JObject.  
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadTokenFrom (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader r) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at shared.api.NotificationConverter.ReadJson (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in /Users/xxx/Projects/xxx/shared/src/api/Notification.cs:23 
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (IWrappedCollection wrappedList, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.String reference, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Failed to deserialize: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Line 2530, position 69.  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer (Char quote) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseString (Char quote) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue (Char currentChar) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader r) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadTokenFrom (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader r) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shared.api.NotificationConverter.ReadJson (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in /Users/xxx/Projects/xxx/shared/src/api/Notification.cs:23 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (IWrappedCollection wrappedList, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.String reference,     Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is the few lines I use for deserializing:

```
using (WebResponse webResponse = requestWeb.GetResponse()) {
    using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream)) {
            using (JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader)) {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Converters.Add(creator);
                rsp = serializer.Deserialize<SimpleServerResponse>(jsonReader);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

It crashes at the JObject.Load(reader):

```
public class NotificationConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return typeof(ANotification).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JObject jobject = JObject.Load(reader);

        object target = null;

        JToken token = jobject["type_id"];

        if (token != null) {
            int id = token.ToObject<int>();

            switch (id) {
                case ANotification.STORY_INVITE:
                    target = new Notification<Moment>();
                    break;
                case ANotification.STORY_CONTENT_ADDED:
                    target = new Notification<Moment>();
                    break;
                case ANotification.STORY_LIKE:
                    target = new Notification<Moment>();
                    break;
                case ANotification.PICTURE_COMMENTED:
                    target = new Notification<PictureMomentPair>();
                    break;
                case ANotification.PICTURE_LIKED:
                    target = new Notification<PictureMomentPair>();
                    break;
                case ANotification.USER_FOLLOW:
                    target = new Notification<User>();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            serializer.Populate(jobject.CreateReader(), target);
        }

        return target;
    }
}
```

Some explanation about my JsonConverter: the objects sent by the server on the JSON file may change depending on the "type_id" value. The JsonConverter try to read the type_id and return the correct object depending on it.

My workaround for now is to read the entire stream in a string and then pass it to the json deserializer, but it is definitely slower on iOS (more CPU consuming).

I don't know why sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Comment: Check if your javascript (or whatever is generating the JSON) is passing undefined values with a valid key.

Comment: The server (in Java, using Jackson) is sending the same JSON at each attempt to the same request, so there is no doubt on this side. Also the problem is avoided when the json.net deserializer reads a string instead of the stream directly.